# What happens to a Kubernetes cluster when 2 of the three masters in a replica set are offline?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I am trying to figure out the minimum number of kubernetes master nodes in a master replica set for kubernetes that will allow the entire cluster to behave as normal. Their official docs mention that you need a of three master nodes.

What happens when you lose 1 of the 3 master nodes? Can you lose two of the master nodes in a replica set and still have the cluster behave as normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes API works as long as Etcd cluster works. Etcd cluster works when there is quorum, so at least 2 of 3 Etcd pods are alive. If only 1 of 3 Etcd pod is alive - cluster goes to read-only state when no new pods can be scheduled and no resource creates/updates/deletes are allowed.

Comment: Thanks! When you say a new pod cant be scheduled that applies to if a pod dies and a new one needs to be spun up?

Comment: Yes, recreating failed pod also implies scheduling decision.

Comment: So in general if you lose Etcd quorum - your cluster goes to very fragile read-only state - everything still works, however it cannot tolerate any failure. BUT if some of your applications depend on updates to Kubernetes objects (like some of modern Kubernetes operators) - they may stop functioning at all.